# How can I change date format in http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/jasoncalendar.htm to date-month-years?

Tags: php, json, datepicker

I picked php datapicker from http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/jasoncalendar.htm

```
<script>DateInput('bornday','required', 'YYYY-MM-DD', '<?php echo $data['bornday']; ?>')</script>
```

It is shown in select datepicker as `Jan 01 1991`.
I tried to show up employee bornday from database.

How can I change it into 01 Jan 1991?

Comment: so what's in `$data['bornday']`?

Comment: a date, i picked it from database using format YYYY-MM-DD (1991-01-01)

Comment: you need to change date format in datepicker files e.g. javascript files.

Comment: There is calendarDateInput.js, but i can't understand which part should be changed.